# How to add dependency path in erlIDE?

Tags: erlide

I put cowboy in my project under deps folder, how to make erlide find it? Or I have to put it under ebin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two use cases that I can see:

1. you want to execute your code while loading even cowboy
2. you want to be able to navigate and search the cowboy code as if it was part of your project

For #2, the only way currently is to make cowboy as part of the project, by adding the paths to the project properties (choose "properties" on the project's context menu and on the "Erlang" tab you can add the additional source and include directories). This will also take care of #1.

In the case where you only have the cowboy beams and want to run with them, you have to configure the launch configuration for the project, on the "Runtimes" tab add the required arguments in "extra args", as you would on the command line (in this case something like "-pa /path/to/deps/cowboy/ebin" without the quotes). Quoting things might be a bit tricky, it's not tested thoroughtly.

regards,
Vlad

Comment: Thanks, and what's the standard way to write .app file in erlide?Just edit it in ebin folder?

Comment: Yes, you have to do it manually, we don't have yet support for .app files. I will see if I can add it in the next release, it's only a small amount of work.

Comment: The next release 0.22 includes a simple support for .app files: any \*.app.src found in the source dirs will be copied to ebin/\*.app. More advanced functionality will be implemented later.

Comment: Cool!I'm looking forward to it.BTW, erlide seems not as stable on Mac OSX as on Windows,often makes eclipse no response,eg. when loading project, creating project, opening project directory...any suggestion?I've tried eclipse 4.2 & 3.6.

Comment: We don't have functionality that is dependent on the platform. It could be related to the platform-dependent parts of Eclipse or to the JVM. It's hard to say (and easy to blame the things that one has no control over). When you see this kind of behaviour, please create a problem report (window->preferences->erlang->report problem) and create a ticket at  https://erlide-tools.assembla.com/spaces/erlide/tickets (there is also a "support" tab if you don't want to register).

Comment: Thanks,I'll keep an eye on it.